# How to remove one religious holiday without removing all religious holidays from Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

My calendar has the holidays in my country by default. One of them is Halloween. This is a holiday that is part of the "(Country) religious holidays." This is not a day I celebrate; I consider it pagan. I don't want it included in my calendar, but I want to keep the rest of the religious holidays.

It seems that I can't remove this holiday without removing all the "religious" holidays. How can I remove a single holiday?

Comment: What happens when you try to delete it and how do you do that?

Comment: I have tried to delete particular holidays from the holiday list in Google Calendar for my country (U.S.A.) but never got it to work. Same is true for religious holidays: Get one, get them all, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If the "(Country) religious holidays" calendar is an external calendar that you subscribe to, then I believe you cannot edit what it imports. Perhaps find a different source for the external calendar that does not contain Halloween. However, a possible workaround is described here that can likely be adapted to your situation: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130291/remove-a-single-event-from-calendar-subscription